# How to transfer data from express to Nuxt

Tags: express, socket.io, nuxt.js, twitch-api

I'm a bit of a noob to the 'backend' part of Nuxt. But I'm trying to learn. I've set up a bot that's linked with Twitch. Their server sends a post to my own environment whenever someone follows or subscribes to a channel. I catch and handle this post with Express and would like to show that event on my Nuxt frontend. Unfortunately, I've yet to figure out how to get that data from the express server middleware to Nuxt whenever it comes in from Twitch. I've tried to find examples on the web, but haven't come across anything that seems to do this... Or I'm just too much of a noob to identify them as solutions.

I figured I'd use something like a WebSocket (Socket.io) to do this, however when instantiating the Express post handler I don't have access to Nuxt. And if I try it after I hand Nuxt to Express with (app.use(nuxt.render)) the post no longer gets passed through.

I also tried to add a store or adding a property to the Nuxt object itself, but again, I'd need Nuxt and the latter wouldn't give me the automatic pushing of data I'm looking for (hence the WebSocket idea).

Currently, the project is set up with a server/index.js where express is handed Nuxt to run the bot. I also have a WebSocket being initialised there. For now, I also handle the post-call there since I thought I'd at least be 'close' to the elements I need (Nuxt / Express) but I just don't see the way forward.

Any tips in the right direction would be much appreciated. If I need to add code to this post I can, at this point though I'm not sure what would help give this question a good answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: depending on your session or auth, use [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action), to set the store on page load (example in the link), then use websockets for realtime if need be

Comment: Hi Lawrence, thanks for your thoughts. Can you maybe expand on that? I've looked into it a little but don't understand how that can make this setup work. As I said, I'm a bit of a noob in this regard...